# Run Javascript clean-up code before object deletion?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I don't think this is possible, but I thought I'd ask anyway. Assume, for example, that I have a constructed object that is closely coupled with another [private] variable in its scope:

```
(function() {

    var coupledVariable = "test", id = 0;
    function Constructor() { this.id = id++; }
    Constructor.prototype.talk = function() {
        if (this.id === 0) { console.log(coupledVariable); }
        else { console.log("something else"); }
    };
    var c = new Constructor();
    c.talk(); // "test"
    new Constructor().talk(); // "something else"
    delete c;

})();
```

Is there a way that I can also delete the `coupledVariable` automatically when the first object, `c`, is deleted, since it is only related to that object. I like keeping it separate from the constructor, since that way it's private (i.e. inaccessible, except via the functions), but this means that it's not garbage collected when the object is deleted. It would be nice if there were a "delete" event listener that ran before object deletion where I could put some code, but I don't think there is.

Comment: In fact, `coupledVariable` goes out of scope right after that last statement, there's no need to "delete" it.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, this is only a very simple non-real-world example, and maybe not the best to illustrate my point. But assume, for the sake of argument, that I made thousands more of these objects before it went out of scope, and that `coupledVariable`, instead of being just a string, was an array storing lots of data in indices equivalent to `this.id`. In that case, it could waste a lot of memory not to delete the data stored at the relevant array index when the object was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's impossible. There are no destructors in JavaScript - and [you cannot `delete` instances anyway](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

> I like keeping it separate from the constructor, since that way it's private (i.e. inaccessible, except via the functions)

You still can trivially keep it private inside the constructor:

```
var id = 0;
function Constructor() {
    this.id = id++;
    if (this.id === 0) {
        var coupledVariable = "test";
        this.talk = function() {
            console.log(coupledVariable);
        };
    }
}
Constructor.prototype.talk = function() {
    console.log("something else");
};
```

Comment: I know about that way of keeping things private, but that removes the benefits of using the prototype (i.e. a new function is created for every object, rather than relying on just one). But if it's impossible, it's impossible! Thanks.

Comment: Well, given that you want privacy for every object, you have to create it :-)

Comment: Fair enough. It seems strange that instantiated objects can't be deleted too, but if that's how the language is, so be it.

Comment: The document I linked says that the `delete` keyword is used for properties, and has nothing to do with memory management. Still, instantiated objects can't be explicitly deleted, JS is an automatically garbage collected language. Just destroy all references to the objects and they're gone.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your own function on that prototype (say  Constructor.prototype.delete).  and invoke that every time you need to delete the private object and delete your private data too.

I would suggest you maintain an object var coupledVariable = {}; and data inside that. So that you really delete the key on that object. If you store your object instances too in an object (a namepsace) then delete might work on object instance otherwise as Bergi mentioned, you cannot really delete object instances just like that.

Comment: Thanks, that's one option. I'd just need to remember to use my own function, but not too troublesome. And yes, in the code I'm actually writing, rather than the example I gave here, `this.id` is used as an array index, `coupledVariable` is an array and the data for each object is stored at the appropriate index.